# Is there anything special I need to do in order to have accessibilityIncrement/accessibilityDecrement called when VoiceOver is on?

Tags: ios, accessibility

I'm making sure an app I'm building is accessible and for the most part enjoying it. However, I'm trying to get `accessibilityIncrement`/`accessibilityDecrement` to work to no avail.

I have a subclass of `UIView` and I'm overriding `accessibleTraits` to return `[super accessibleTraits] | UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable;` and I've implemented

In all other respects the view responds well when VoiceOver is on but the only method on `UIAccessibilityAction` I seem to be able to get to work with a 3 finger swipe up/down is `accessibleScroll`.

Has anyone else encountered this? What am I missing?

Comment: The action for `accessibilityIncrement` and `accessibilityDecrement` is a _one_ finger swipe up or down.

Comment: Can't get it to work either. Trying since 48 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Your description looks correct: All that you need to do is set `UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable` and then implement `accessibilityIncrement` and `accessibilityDecrement`. The normal trick is that Apple's documentation implies you do this on the view controller - that is not the case you should implement them on the view itself.

That in turn means you need a delegate protocol or some other call back mechanism with your view controller to communicate the changes to your model (and other parts of your view).
so:"

```
@interface MyAdjustableView : UIView

@end


@implementation MyAdjustableView

- (UIAccessibilityTraits)accessibilityTraits; {
    return [super accessibilityTraits] |  UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable;

}

- (void)accessibilityIncrement {
    NSLog(@"increment");
}

- (void)accessibilityDecrement {
    NSLog(@"decrement");

}

@end
```

should work. Delegate boilerplate left as an exercise.